# Redeeming Minecraft Windows 10 Edition

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-bedrock-edition

So, I basically bought Minecraft early, so I am able to redeem the Windows 10 Edition. However, when I went to the redeem page, and attempting to redeem the code, the windows page said that the code had already been redeemed. Checking my microsoft account, it didn't have minecraft on it[image]. Any way I can re-redeem it? I never played the Windows 10 version, and messaging the support center, they just sent me how to redeem the code normally.

Comment: Wait didn't mean to post two pictures, but eh

Comment: If the code was already used, I dont think we can help you any further. Are you sure you are checking the right Microsoft account (do you have more than one?)  Besides that, you'll have to work with their support team.